# RouteContext as constructor parameter or method parameter in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have this simple class where I load an object from the database and store it into the `RouteContext.DataTokens` because I need to access it through out the request.

In this example the `RouteContext` is injected via the constructor but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do here, maybe the `RouteContext`should be a method parameter instead?

```
public class RouteResolverTrie : IRouteResolverTrie
{
    private readonly IDocumentStore documentStore;
    private RouteContext context;

    public RouteResolverTrie(RouteContext context, IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        this.documentStore = documentStore;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Trie LoadTrie()
    {
        if(context.DataTokens.ContainsKey("some key")) {
            return context.DataTokens["trie"] as Trie;
        }
        else {
            using(var session = documentStore.OpenSession()) {
                var trie = session.Load<Trie>("trie/1");
                context.DataTokens["trie"] = trie;
                return trie;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the routing works in vNext and this is my first entry point. As you can see I use `LoadTrie()` in the method `RouteAsync` which in turn uses the RouteContext to store temporary data through out the request. So, the question is, should I instantiate the `DefaultRouter` with a new `RouteResolverTrie` that takes the current `RouteContext` as a constructor parameter or should it be a method parameter?

```
public class DefaultRoute : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _target;
    private IRouteResolverTrie _routeResolverTrie;

    public DefaultRoute(IRouter target, IRouteResolverTrie routeResolverTrie) {
        _target = target;
        _routeResolverTrie = routeResolverTrie;
    }

    public string GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        var trie = _routeResolverTrie.LoadTrie();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need something that persists for the duration of request, a better place would be to add to `RequestContext`. So there are couple of ways to handle this more cleanly:

Add a base controller and add additional data to `RequestContext`:

```
protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    // get additional data
    ...

    // add them to routeDate
    requestContext.RouteData.Values.Add(key, value);
    ...

    base.Execute(requestContext);
}
```

Add your own custom `RouteHandler` and add additional data to `RequestContext`:

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler 
{ 

    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext){
           // add to HttpContext
           requestContext.HttpContext.Items["Custom"] = data;

           // or RouteData
           requestContext.RouteData.Values.Add(key, value);
        }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }

}

// define route with custom handler 
Route customRoute = new Route (
    url: ...,
    defaults: null,
    constraints: ...,
    routeHandler: new CustomRouteHandler()
});

routes.Add(customRoute);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using ASP.NET vNext but I guess I can replace the RouteHandler. I don't know if I like the idea of loading additional stuff in the RouteHandler, in my example the RouteResolverTrie has a well defined responsibility, to load and "cache" the Trie, but if I move this to a CustomRouteHandler it wouldn't be as clear or what do you think?

Comment: If you think about it, `RouteResolverTrie` is your custom `RouteHandler`. Only thing is that now it'll be modifying something it is ***supposed*** to!

Comment: In other words, that's what CustomRouteHandlers are meant to do - it makes it explicit and cleaner because you know exactly who's modifying the route.

Comment: I see, in MVC 6/vNext there are no split between the router and the http handler. I have updated my question with a simple IRouter implementation and I hope you understand what I try to do.